# Resolve pipenv lock failure

Tags: python, pipenv

I have, in my `Pipfile`:

```
# Pipfile
[packages]
# ...snip
papermill = "==2.3.2"
scrapbook = "==0.5.0"
# ..snip
```

And when I run `pipenv install`:

```
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Cannot install -r /var/folders/0j/k5jvgl_d4yg82n5qtpwhxw5r0000gp/T/pipenv-jcwtak48-requirements/pipenv-10yslvrt-constraints.txt (line
7), nteract-scrapbook==0.3.1, papermill==2.3.2, papermill==1.2.1, papermill==2.0.0, papermill==2.1.0, papermill==2.1.1, papermill==2.1.2, papermill==2.1.3, papermill==2.2.0, papermill==2.2.2,
papermill==2.3.0, papermill==2.3.1, papermill==2.3.3, papermill==2.3.4 and papermill==2.4.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

...snip

INFO:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:
The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.4.0 depends on papermill 2.4.0 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.4.0/papermill-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=baa76f0441257d9a25b3ad7c895e761341b94f9a70ca98cf419247fc728932d9 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.7))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.3.4 depends on papermill 2.3.4 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.3.4/papermill-2.3.4-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=81eb9aa3dbace9772cd6287f5af8deef64c6659d9ace0b2761db05068233bf77 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.3.3 depends on papermill 2.3.3 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.3.3/papermill-2.3.3-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=d1dadee33b3b2bcd54664f4736b5ff40786b88e3a460e66131485cd3650a16d0 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.3.1 depends on papermill 2.3.1 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.3.1/papermill-2.3.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=20675b9f4ae6e18d26bce70bfc9876021b5ef36205dd0f14d7a2c9c15edae146 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.3.0 depends on papermill 2.3.0 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.3.0/papermill-2.3.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=00586c9dd3926efc8f3092ebd95d6595629c5cb35d35425fc8de97523362c4af (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.2.2 depends on papermill 2.2.2 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.2.2/papermill-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=761db2d6f478228f9152772e35aa05bf0e6e6eebcb63687d7e1970c44b316bfb (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.2.0 depends on papermill 2.2.0 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.2.0/papermill-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=1ae18e759ce5a12667e301e479592d092d59643eded2db7b5c4e9a8902dc2d22 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.1.3 depends on papermill 2.1.3 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.1.3/papermill-2.1.3-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=fa88ab798ae73f7add8f65d7c710a93fc2e2e608ddc3dc5eb4ef6f60edd888cd (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.1.2 depends on papermill 2.1.2 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.1.2/papermill-2.1.2-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=cf08d505d3074098f1f1d15ad0bafc4d33e8a185dec2a92abb8dbd51e75e56e5 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.1.1 depends on papermill 2.1.1 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.1.1/papermill-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8d9c311c122b07fbbfb364c864fc48d8fff2ea7051d6384e0bcb75015b8ebe5b (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.1.0 depends on papermill 2.1.0 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.1.0/papermill-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=10f86551cd28d09acea1f63b04a61d061ed4c3d3e82aa675b6a593c4451860c6 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.6))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 2.0.0 depends on papermill 2.0.0 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/2.0.0/papermill-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=7ad0dd5bce86df5e973a88e29457be99662099d365b99d640acb27119b1b7812 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/) (requires-python:>=3.5))
    The user requested papermill==2.3.2
    scrapbook 0.5.0 depends on papermill
    nteract-scrapbook[all] 0.3.1 depends on papermill
    papermill[all] 1.2.1 depends on papermill 1.2.1 (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/packages/papermill/1.2.1/papermill-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=a3c69481b057dc53314e16e5a802e5b82f0923f15b12e8c4dc6d3d686d3d051b (from https://nexus.bll/repository/pypi-all/simple/papermill/))
To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/kurtwall/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 648, in _main
[ResolutionFailure]:       pre, clear, verbose, system, write, requirements_dir, packages, category
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/kurtwall/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 622, in resolve_packages
[ResolutionFailure]:       requirements_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/kurtwall/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 603, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=requirements_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/kurtwall/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 857, in resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       req_dir=req_dir,
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/kurtwall/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 621, in actually_resolve_deps
[ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
[ResolutionFailure]:   File "/Users/kurtwall/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 447, in resolve
[ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv run pip install <requirement_name> to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the versions actually installed in the virtualenv.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

I'm confused as to why `pipenv` would understand that I've selected the `papermill` dependency at `2.3.2`, which depends on libraries with an open dependency (see output: `scrapbook==0.5.0 depends on papermill`; note the lack of version), and continually try different scrapbook versions.

Why is `pipenv lock` failing?

```
$ pipenv install

...snip
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```